# Running an executable in a loop

Tags: unix, executable

I have a test (which is basically an executable) which I want to run several times .Is there like some sort of script or something to do this?Basically I want to run

```
terminal>./test   and do this like n times.
```

This is for the command line.

p.s I did not name the executable test ..I just used a mneumonic to help what I was saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
for i in `seq 1 $n`; do ./test ; done
```

This should work on all sh-like shells. As a side note, naming an executable "test" is not the best idea:

```
# there's a shell builtin
[cnicutar@fresh ~]$ type test
test is a shell builtin

# and a separate executable, for good measure
[cnicutar@fresh ~]$ which test
/usr/bin/test
```

Comment: is that a stray `1` after `in` ?

Answer (score 2):

Don't call `test` your program.

You can use *repeat* builtin of zsh, e.g.

```
 repeat 12 ./test
```

Comment: Yes, it is a zsh builtin, not a bash one.... This is one of the many reasons why I prefer zsh as an interactive shell...